# "Container View does not have a IBSegueTriggerViewDidLoad binding" warning in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

This warning is visible under the Triggered Segues section when right-clicking a container view added in a fresh Xcode macOS project. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: Sadly, no. Also no answer on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running into this as well.